# MapStruct map parent field to child array of objects

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
class Item {
    String oneTo
}

class Header {
    String twoTo;
    List <Item> items;
}


class HeaderFrom {
    String oneFrom;
    String twoFrom;
}
```

In the above example, I need to map the following scenarios using MapStruct. What is the best way to get this done?

`oneFrom -> all the oneTo fields in the list`

`twoFrom -> twoTo`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
@Mapping(source = "oneFrom", target = "items", qualifiedByName = "oneFromToList")
Header headerFromToHeader(HeaderFrom headerFrom);
```

In the same mapper class add a method

```
@Named("oneFromToList")
public static String oneFromToList(List<> input) {
    // logic to map Item.oneTo = HeaderFrom.oneFrom
}
```